# Layout Recommendation

Tags: android, android-layout

Developing applications on Android. I want to design a screen similar to the structure of the master page.(ASP.net)
I want to change the middle part of the screen by selecting different button.
How can i do it. i have tried Fragment  but I could not do so well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By Fragment you can do it for sure, but if there is any issue with fragment implementation, then make all your activities and reuse layouts by mergelayout and includelayout.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a different layouts with a different IDs.
2. Include all of this to the main layout.
3. Then use a `layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE)` and `layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` within java code to switch between visible layouts.